# How to add row in datatable - DC.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a json file that loads sales data for salespeople based on the current year and the previous year.

I created a table in which I show the total sales for each year for each salesperson and, in the last row, I need to load the total for all salespeople added up. As shown in the image below:

[image]

I am using `dc.dataTable` to create my table.

Can you tell me if there is any way in DC.js to create a row in my table to put the total sales?

Here is my code, thank you in advance.

```js
var vendedorTable = dc.dataTable("#Vendedores");

var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgsUhkPSjS?indent=2';
d3.json(url).then(function(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {

    var myCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var all = myCrossfilter.groupAll();

    dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
      .dimension(myCrossfilter)
      .group(all);

    vendedorDim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.vendnm;
    });

    var vendedorGroup = vendedorDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
      p.totalAno += +v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo += +v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
      p.totalAno -= v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo -= v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
      return {
        totalAno: 0,
        totalHomologo: 0,
      };
    }

    // formatter = d3.format(".3s");
    // formatter2 = d3.format(".0%");

    //Fake Dimension
    rank = function(p) {
      return ""
    };

    function checkRows(d) {
      if (d.value.totalAno <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalAno) || d.value.totalHomologo <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalHomologo)) {
        return 0;
      }
      return d;
    }

    //vendedorTable
    vendedorTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(vendedorGroup)
      .group(rank)
      .columns([function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return d.key;
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        }
      ])
      .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno
      })
      .order(d3.descending)

    vendedorTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
        .on('click', function(d) {
          let filters = table.filters().slice();
          if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
            filters.push(d.key);
          else
            filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
          if (filters.length === 0)
            vendedorDim.filter(null);
          else
            vendedorDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
              return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
            })

          table.replaceFilter([filters]);
          dc.redrawAll();
        });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
    });

    dc.renderAll();

  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null)

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null)

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

});
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .dc-table-group {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
    
    tr.dc-table-row.sel-rows {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.8/dc.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.js"></script>

  <title>Vendedores</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="row marginClass">
          <h4 class="pull-left" id="Introduction"><small>Dados fictícios da empresa | Exemplo de Pesquisa
                            Detalhada |
                        </small></h4>
          <h6 class="dc-data-count" style="float: left;margin-left:5px;">
            <span>
                            <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of
            <span class="total-count"></span> records |
            <a id="reset"> Reset All </a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <br>
          <a id="resetTable"> Reset</a>
          <table class="table" id="Vendedores">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sales</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dc.js is the frontend for crossfilter, which is an in-memory database for JavaScript that is tuned for these kinds of dashboards.

You always want to add data on the database side. So the right place to look is in the crossfilter API, and here it is: [crossfilter.add()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_add)

I might have just left a comment, but since you were nice enough to include running code, let's try it out!

First, let's reserve one of the vendors out of the dataset:

```
  rows = data0.filter(d => d.vendnm === 'JOÃO LUIS');
  var data = data0.filter(d => d.vendnm !== 'JOÃO LUIS');
```

Then, when the Add Row button is clicked, let's add that data and redraw all the associated charts:

```
  $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    myCrossfilter.add(rows);
    dc.redrawAll();
  });
```

Notice that if you click Add Row multiple times, the sales for that vendor will double, then triple, because we are displaying an aggregated group, so that vendor gets more and more sales added in.

That's all there is to it!

```js
var vendedorTable = dc.dataTable("#Vendedores");
// lift crossfilter and row so they are visible to addRow handler
var myCrossfilter, rows;

var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgsUhkPSjS?indent=2';
d3.json(url).then(function(data0) {

  // save Joao for later
  rows = data0.filter(d => d.vendnm === 'JOÃO LUIS');
  var data = data0.filter(d => d.vendnm !== 'JOÃO LUIS');

  data.forEach(function(d) {

    myCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var all = myCrossfilter.groupAll();

    dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
      .dimension(myCrossfilter)
      .group(all);

    vendedorDim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.vendnm;
    });

    var vendedorGroup = vendedorDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
      p.totalAno += +v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo += +v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
      p.totalAno -= v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo -= v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
      return {
        totalAno: 0,
        totalHomologo: 0,
      };
    }

    // formatter = d3.format(".3s");
    // formatter2 = d3.format(".0%");

    //Fake Dimension
    rank = function(p) {
      return ""
    };

    function checkRows(d) {
      if (d.value.totalAno <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalAno) || d.value.totalHomologo <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalHomologo)) {
        return 0;
      }
      return d;
    }

    //vendedorTable
    vendedorTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(vendedorGroup)
      .group(rank)
      .columns([function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return d.key;
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        }
      ])
      .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno
      })
      .order(d3.descending)

    vendedorTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
        .on('click', function(d) {
          let filters = table.filters().slice();
          if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
            filters.push(d.key);
          else
            filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
          if (filters.length === 0)
            vendedorDim.filter(null);
          else
            vendedorDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
              return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
            })

          table.replaceFilter([filters]);
          dc.redrawAll();
        });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
    });

    dc.renderAll();

  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null)

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null)

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    myCrossfilter.add(rows);
    dc.redrawAll();
  });

});
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .dc-table-group {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
    
    tr.dc-table-row.sel-rows {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.8/dc.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.js"></script>

  <title>Vendedores</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="row marginClass">
          <h4 class="pull-left" id="Introduction"><small>Dados fictícios da empresa | Exemplo de Pesquisa
                            Detalhada |
                        </small></h4>
          <h6 class="dc-data-count" style="float: left;margin-left:5px;">
            <span>
                            <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of
            <span class="total-count"></span> records |
            <a id="reset"> Reset All </a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a id="addRow"> Add Row </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <br>
          <a id="resetTable"> Reset</a>
          <table class="table" id="Vendedores">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sales</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, I think I understand what you explained, I will create a method for crossfilter.add() with the total sales. By the way, I've been studying D3.js, DC.js and Crossfilter for a few months and I realized that here at StackOverfllow you help people a lot. This is the second time that guides me in less than 36 hours, and thank you for that.

Comment: I just posted a question here on the stackoverflow regarding a challenge that I was given at work. I've been working on it for a few months and I still haven't been able to resolve it. If you can look and give me any tips/guidance of what to do I really appreciate it!!! I'm stuck on this project and I don't know what else to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952879/how-to-create-graph-with-two-tables-being-all-dynamic