# How to remove empty rows in tables when they are zero, and how to allow selection in only one table at a time?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I created two tables that relate. When I select one or more items from Table A, Table B is resized according to that selection and vice versa.

However, I need to lock the selection of the two tables at the same time. For example, if I click on the sellers `Miguel` and`Sede`, in Table B the values and cities corresponding to these two sellers will be rendered. And if in Table B I click on the cities of `Faro` and`Loulé`, automatically the sellers `Miguel` and`Sede` should be deselected.

What happens at the moment is that I can make selections in both tables at the same time, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I need to create a rule where if I have a selection in Table A and click on Table B. The line selected in Table A has no background color and vice versa.

When I make a selection, some lines are empty, but they still appear, as shown in the image below:

[image]

How can I prevent these lines from appearing if there is no selection?

I apologize for asking two questions at the same time, as it is the same code I have found better to use here.

Here's my code, thanks in advance.

```js
var vendedorTable = dc.dataTable("#Vendedores");
var citiesTable = dc.dataTable("#cities");

var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bernalvinicius/3cece295bc37de1697e7f83418e7fcc9/raw/a5820379ec6eae76ee792495cc5dd1685c977a73/vendedores.json';
d3.json(url).then(function(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {

    var myCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var all = myCrossfilter.groupAll();

    dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
      .dimension(myCrossfilter)
      .group(all);

    vendedorDim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.vendnm;
    });
    var vendedorGroup = vendedorDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    citiesDim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.zona;
    });
    var citiesGroup = citiesDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
      p.totalAno += +v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo += +v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
      p.totalAno -= v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo -= v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
      return {
        totalAno: 0,
        totalHomologo: 0,
      };
    }

    //Fake Dimension
    rank = function(p) {
      return ""
    };

    function checkRows(d) {
      if (d.value.totalAno <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalAno) || d.value.totalHomologo <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalHomologo)) {
        return 0;
      }
      return d;
    }

    //vendedorTable
    vendedorTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(vendedorGroup)
      .group(rank)
      .columns([function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return d.key;
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        }
      ])
      .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno
      })
      .order(d3.descending)

    //CityTable
    citiesTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(citiesGroup)
      .group(rank)
      .columns([function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return d.key;
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        }
      ])
      .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno
      })
      .order(d3.descending)

    vendedorTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
        .on('click', function(d) {
          let filters = table.filters().slice();
          if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
            filters.push(d.key);
          else
            filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
          if (filters.length === 0)
            vendedorDim.filter(null);
          else
            vendedorDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
              return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
            })
          table.replaceFilter([filters]);
          dc.redrawAll();
        });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
    });

    citiesTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
        .on('click', function(d) {
          let filters = table.filters().slice();
          if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
            filters.push(d.key);
          else
            filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
          if (filters.length === 0)
            citiesDim.filter(null);
          else
            citiesDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
              return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
            })
          table.replaceFilter([filters]);
          dc.redrawAll();
        });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
    });

    dc.renderAll();

  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable2').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

});
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .dc-table-group {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
    
    tr.dc-table-row.sel-rows {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.8/dc.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.js"></script>

  <title>Vendedores</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="row marginClass">
          <h4 class="pull-left" id="Introduction"><small>Dados fictícios da empresa | Exemplo de Pesquisa
                            Detalhada |
                        </small></h4>
          <h6 class="dc-data-count" style="float: left;margin-left:5px;">
            <span>
                            <span class="filter-count"></span> selecionado dentre
            <span class="total-count"></span> registros |
            <a id="reset"> Reset All </a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <br>
          <a id="resetTable"> Reset</a>
          <table class="table" id="Vendedores">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sales</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <br>
          <a id="resetTable2"> Reset</a>
          <table class="table" id="cities">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the first question.

As for the second question, currently you are filtering out the data inside of the formatting functions for the table:

```
  .columns([function(d) {
      d = checkRows(d);
      while (d != 0) {
        return d.key;
      }
    },
    function(d) {
      d = checkRows(d);
      while (d != 0) {
        return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }) + '€';
      }
    },
    function(d) {
      d = checkRows(d);
      while (d != 0) {
        return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }) + '€';
      }
    }
  ])
```

That works, but it's a weird way to go about it for two reasons:

1. `while(...)` means "repeat until false". `if(...)` would be more idiomatic here.
2. More importantly, this still prints the rows, but if the values are zero or NaN, it prints `undefined` (the default return value for a function in JavaScript) and this shows up as an empty cell.

It would be better to filter the data before it gets to the table. You can do this using a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups). Specifically, you can create an object which supports the `.top(N)` function that the table will use to pull data, but skips any rows where either of these values is close to zero:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        top: function (N) {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value.totalAno > 1e-3 &&
                  d.value.totalHomologo > 1e-3; // does it have a value?
            }).slice(0, N);
        }
    };
}
```

Apply this function to each of your groups:

```
    vendedorTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(remove_empty_bins(vendedorGroup))

    citiesTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(remove_empty_bins(citiesGroup))
```

And now your formatting functions can stick to formatting!

```
      .columns([function(d) {
            return d.key;
        },
        function(d) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
        },
        function(d) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
        }
      ])
```

```js
var vendedorTable = dc.dataTable("#Vendedores");
var citiesTable = dc.dataTable("#cities");

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
return {
    top: function (N) {
        return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
            return d.value.totalAno > 1e-3 &&
              d.value.totalHomologo > 1e-3; // does it have a value?
        }).slice(0, N);
    }
};
}
var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bernalvinicius/3cece295bc37de1697e7f83418e7fcc9/raw/a5820379ec6eae76ee792495cc5dd1685c977a73/vendedores.json';
d3.json(url).then(function(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {

    var myCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);
    var all = myCrossfilter.groupAll();

    dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
      .dimension(myCrossfilter)
      .group(all);

    vendedorDim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.vendnm;
    });
    var vendedorGroup = vendedorDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    citiesDim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function(d) {
      return d.zona;
    });
    var citiesGroup = citiesDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
      p.totalAno += +v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo += +v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
      p.totalAno -= v.Vendas_Ano;
      p.totalHomologo -= v.Vendas_Ant;
      return p;
    }

    function reduceInitial() {
      return {
        totalAno: 0,
        totalHomologo: 0,
      };
    }

    //Fake Dimension
    rank = function(p) {
      return ""
    };

    function checkRows(d) {
      if (d.value.totalAno <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalAno) || d.value.totalHomologo <= 0 || isNaN(d.value.totalHomologo)) {
        return 0;
      }
      return d;
    }

    //vendedorTable
    vendedorTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(remove_empty_bins(vendedorGroup))
      .group(rank)
      .columns([function(d) {
            return d.key;
        },
        function(d) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
        },
        function(d) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
        }
      ])
      .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno
      })
      .order(d3.descending)

    //CityTable
    citiesTable.width(500)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(remove_empty_bins(citiesGroup))
      .group(rank)
      .columns([function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return d.key;
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        },
        function(d) {
          d = checkRows(d);
          while (d != 0) {
            return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
            }) + '€';
          }
        }
      ])
      .sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno
      })
      .order(d3.descending)

    vendedorTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
        .on('click', function(d) {
          let filters = table.filters().slice();
          if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
            filters.push(d.key);
          else
            filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
          if (filters.length === 0)
            vendedorDim.filter(null);
          else
            vendedorDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
              return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
            })
          table.replaceFilter([filters]);
          dc.redrawAll();
        });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
    });

    citiesTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
        .on('click', function(d) {
          let filters = table.filters().slice();
          if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
            filters.push(d.key);
          else
            filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
          if (filters.length === 0)
            citiesDim.filter(null);
          else
            citiesDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
              return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
            })
          table.replaceFilter([filters]);
          dc.redrawAll();
        });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
    });

    dc.renderAll();

  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable2').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

});
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .dc-table-group {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
    
    tr.dc-table-row.sel-rows {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.8/dc.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.js"></script>

  <title>Vendedores</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="row marginClass">
          <h4 class="pull-left" id="Introduction"><small>Dados fictícios da empresa | Exemplo de Pesquisa
                            Detalhada |
                        </small></h4>
          <h6 class="dc-data-count" style="float: left;margin-left:5px;">
            <span>
                            <span class="filter-count"></span> selecionado dentre
            <span class="total-count"></span> registros |
            <a id="reset"> Reset All </a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <br>
          <a id="resetTable"> Reset</a>
          <table class="table" id="Vendedores">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sales</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <br>
          <a id="resetTable2"> Reset</a>
          <table class="table" id="cities">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I will remove this from the while. I had thought that `rank = function (p) {return" "};` solved my problems in relation to zero and undefined values. But filtering before the data reached the table worked perfectly here. I edited my first question and explained it better. Thanks @Gordon