# Add sum row at end DataTable dc.js/reactJS

Tags: dc.js

I have been given task at work place to make sum row and since am still in process of learning dc.js/d3.js and quite stuck in progress to solve this. How can i add sum row at end of table?

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-shape-g7o2b?file=/src/MyComponent.js

At work they are sending group as dimension, but don't know how to make it work

Comment: Thanks for including a running example. I think this question has already been answered, did you try searching SO for `[dc.js] table sum` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the total sales and make the displayed totals dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303993/how-to-calculate-the-total-sales-and-make-the-displayed-totals-dynamic)

Comment: Hei Gordon, thanks for making our lives with dc much more easier, you rocks. Well it does helps to some extent. Does i have to use dc.numberDisplay for representing sum row? Can i somehow append row to dimension(group)? Also updated example with data that i use but don't know what is problem with sending group as dimension

Comment: I guess you could also append the totals to the group. It won’t have any special style unless you do extra work. Is your concern that you don’t want to change the HTML source of the table?

Comment: i cannot change html source of table, since we are using "middleman" between our component and dc. So in my example myComponent is my component that im working on and i can change whatever i need in order to make it work, DataTable is "middleman" component between mine and dc.js DataTable, if that makes sense to you

Comment: Not a great design, but I hear you, often projects will be structured that way. Could you please fix the sandbox? Today it is displaying NaNs, yesterday it was ok.

Comment: after quite some time managed to fix it and use real data. Example is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A previous answer described how to add a row using `dc.numberDisplay` and a `<tfoot>` row:

[How to calculate the total sales and make the displayed totals dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303993/how-to-calculate-the-total-sales-and-make-the-displayed-totals-dynamic)

However, if you can't modify the HTML, you can also display a total row by computing it using a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups).

The idea is to create an object which supports `.all()` and `.top()`, the methods the data table will use to pull data. When it returns the data, it will add another entry with the totals:

```
return {
  all: () => {
    let all = orig_group.all();
    const total = all.reduce(
      (p, v) => {
        range(ship_size_id_start, ship_size_id_end).forEach(
          i => (p.value[i] = (p.value[i] || 0) + (v.value[i] || 0))
        );
        p.value.sum += v.value.sum;
        return p;
      },
      { key: "Total", value: { sum: 0 } }
    );
    all = all.concat([total]);
    return all;
  },
  top: function(N) {
    return this.all().slice(0, N);
  }
};
```

This grabs the original data using `orig_group.all()`, then uses `Array.reduce` to find the sums. The `Array.reduce` function loops over all the ship size ids and sums the columns, and also sums the sums for a grand total.

I had to declare

```
const ship_size_id_start = 1,
  ship_size_id_end = 8;
```

in order to know what to loop over.

I also had to add the translation

```
Total: "Total"
```

for the title to show up in the left column.

[image: screenshot of table with Total row]
[Fork of your code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-monad-yl224?file=/src/MyComponent.js).

#### bolding the totals line

You can still bold the last line without editing the DataTable component; however you will need a unique selector (like a div with an `#id`) in order to do this safely.

So the following CSS works

```
table.data-table.dc-chart tbody tr:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

but it will style all dc data tables on the page, so be careful. I added it to the styles in my fork.

[image: bolded total screenshot]

Comment: You really rocks Gordon. If there is any way i would like to buy you a coffee :) will implement your solution in my code, Thanks a lot

Comment: You can do this with CSS, but see my warning above.